# Why function inside while loop does not work?

Tags: javascript, function, while-loop

I want to use `while` loop for looping and activating function 5 times. But I have problems making function `myFunction` work inside the `while` loop. The loop works by itself if I remove the function. What’s wrong?

```js
var c = 0;
var p = 0;

while (c < 5 && p < 5) {
  function myFunction() { // How to make this function work?
    c++;
    document.write(c);
  }

  if (c == 5) {
    document.write(c);
    document.write('computer win');
  }
  else if (p == 5) {
    document.write('player win');
  }
}
```

Comment: You are declaring a function in  the loop but aren't calling it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    var c = 0;
    var p = 0;

    function myFunction() {

        c++;
        document.write(c);
    }


while (c < 5 && p < 5) {

    myFunction();

    if (c == 5) {
        document.write(c);
        document.write('computer win');
    } else if (p == 5) {
        document.write('player win');
    }

}
```

In JavaScript or any other language, you have to define the function to invoke it. And defining a function inside a loop is a very bad practice probably gives an error.

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring a function in  the loop but aren't calling it.

```js
function myFunction() { // how to make this function work?
  c++;
  document.write (c); 
} 

var c = 0;
var p = 0;

while ( c < 5 && p < 5) {
  myFunction();
  if ( c == 5 ) {
    document.write (c); 
    document.write ('computer win');
  } else if ( p == 5 ) {
    document.write ('player win');
  }
}
```

Comment: c is not defined

Comment: @AsiriH. Press _"Run code snippet"_ and see how it works. Variable declarations are hoisted in JavaScript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting

Comment: @AsiriH. it is when the function is called.

Answer (score -1):

You didn't invoke the function, merely declared it.